# What winapi functions does QT use to display text?

Tags: winapi, qt, text

I'm interested in WinApi functions that QT uses to display text (on buttons, etc.)

Any input will be appreaciated.

Edit:
I'm interested in the particular functions which are used, that is, their names. Let's say we have a QLabel with text set, now, what gdi/user32 function will be called in the end to get the text out.

Comment: Text on Windows buttons is drawn by the Windows API and not by apps calling a function to draw the text. There's not really a question here.

Comment: @David: I improved the question a bit.

Comment: QT is open source ... just look at the source.

Comment: Labels would likely call DrawText or DrawTextEx since they offer the ability to underline shortcut keys. And as Brian says, you can just read the source.

Comment: @David: I would download the source, but I'm running exceptionally low on disk space, so it won't fit. I'll have a new HDD on monday, but I need this particular thing done asap. Thing is, I wanna intercept a QT4 app's output and need to hook a function.  Neither DrawTextEx nor ExtTextOut intercept the data. I'm interested in the contents of such a window: [link](http://img607.imageshack.us/img607/6149/windowr.png)

Comment: You originally said button. Now you say label. Which do you want?

Comment: @David: Added precisely what I want.

Comment: Actually QLabel could very well be a windowed control implemented with a STATIC window class. You could easily check this with Spy++. I know little of Qt, but I do know a bit about Windows API.

Comment: Spy++ was precisely what I started with, unfortunately, the window in question doesn't yield to it, and is a single window, without subwindows.

Comment: There are lots of child windows on the window in your screenshot. Is the window in an app written by you? Do you have the source code?

Comment: I don't. And the problem is, while it LOOKS like there are child windows there, Spy++ doesn't recognize any. This has to have something to do with the fact we're dealing with a qt-managed window.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why Spy++ doesn't see any child windows is because the windows you're seeing is actually one big window and Qt draws in the buttons. So these buttons you see don't have their own `HWND`s. Qt happens to also implement some kind of event system so that when you "click" on a "button" it does something. They are what we call "lightweight" controls or ["windowless" controls](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/11/371042.aspx).

It's the same way Internet Explorer and Firefox works. The buttons you see on a webpage are drawn by the rendering engine and the browser simulates button clicks.

For this reason looking at how Qt works is actually a pretty bad way to learn how the Windows API works. The code that interfaces with the Windows API is buried deep in the source. Qt is a cross-platform framework, so it can't expose the Windows API in the public interface.

If you want to start out with the Windows API, [you can start with this tutorial](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/). It'll show how you can create windows, buttons etc. with nothing but C++ and the Windows API in a step-by-step fashion.

Note that the Windows API is not a GUI toolkit (even though everyone seems to think it is). It's low-level application interface to the operating system itself, providing the primitives needed (e.g. files, windows, threads, networking, etc.) to implement your application programs. That's why you'll see many people use a framework or a library (like Qt, FLTK, WxWidgets, etc.) or write up their own.

Comment: Has this always been so? I though Qt used native widgets.

Comment: @David Heffernan: I believe that has always been the case. Qt may use the OS's theming API to draw the buttons so they look exactly like their native equivalents, but otherwise they are fully drawn by Qt itself.

Comment: I've been working with WinApi for over 10 years, so it's unnecessary to tell me what this is. I've actually managed to get a laptop and download the source, so I've discovered that aswell. I've also discovered how to intercept the data I want, so I believe the issue to be solved :). Thanks for your time, though.

Comment: @RSuthke: Ah, sorry about that. You came off as a person who isn't as familiar as the Windows API as I thought in your question. Still, the tutorial link has lots of information on how to do basic GUI operatings in the Windows API, [like this one for drawing text](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/fonts.html).

Comment: I'm familiar with the techniques in that tutorial :). Qt actually draws its own letters, so it is highly useless for my problem at hand.

Comment: @In silico Ah, theme APIs to draw, that makes sense. I've obviously had the wrong end of the stick for some time! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Qt does use `CreateWindowEx` only when it creates Top level windows, or any REAL Windows (e.g. `Qt::Window` or `Qt::Tool` flag set).

The rest is emulated. Qt is taking the bitmaps from UxTheme on Windows and uses it's own routines for everything - events, messages, event loop, rendering.

These magics that you see - Native windows with 3d Effects.... They are actually non native, they only LOOK native. They are UxTheme's bitmaps converted to OpenGL Textures (or Direct3D Textures) and rendered with the GPU.

It appeared that Qt CALLS `TextOut` sometime, but not always. For example, own font rendering occurs in QGLWidgets or if GraphicsEffect is set.

So your answer is: go check in the source. The way QT renders everything is interesting, but not relying on API functions like GDI TextOut.

It will be extremely difficult to hook into Qt apps with the Windows' way.

Comment: Got around to it and got my thing working now :).